# how to get data from selected portion of pie in plotly

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, ggplotly, r-plotly

[please have a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q15eF.png)

I want to get the data from a selected portion of pie suppose i select the blue portion as in figure so i get the data from that portion i.e. February

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    usvltdyearstore1 = data.frame(
      Sold_that_area=as.numeric(as.character(usvltdprodmonyear$QTY)),
      Month =usvltdprodmonyear$MONTHNAME,
      TOTAL= usvltdprodmonyear$TOTAL,
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
    output$usvltdmonthprod=renderPlotly({


    n1<-plot_ly(usvltdyearstore1,labels = ~Month,values = ~TOTAL, type = 'pie',textinfo = "none")%>%add_pie(hole = 0.6)

})  
})
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: any approach or help still stuck into it

Comment: I don't understand what you want, but if you want people to help you, you should have a reproducible example.

Comment: i want to add click event on pie